# Formatting query outputs in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset

I am attempting to sum a list of entries. However, I can't seem to figure out how to extract the numbers I need.

Whenever I run:

`Entry.objects.aggregate(Sum('euros_sum'))`

I get:

```
{'euros_sum__sum': Decimal('5948.48')}
```

Which is fine if I need to add the number to my template. However, I need the number (`5948.48`) by itself so that I may add it to a form field. How do I format the query to only output the total without the field details(`euros_sum__sum: Decimal`, etc)?

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of a *value alias* might be in handy here (`s` is the alias, you can name it whatever you like). Note that `aggregate` returns a `dict`, so you can simply `.get` the aliased value:

```
d = Entry.objects.aggregate(s=Sum('euros_sum')).get('s') 
d  # Decimal('5948.48')
type(d)  # <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

or

```
d = Entry.objects.aggregate(s=Sum('euros_sum')).get('s')
str(d)  # '5948.48'
type(str(d))  # <class 'str'>
```